How to create a bar chart with date dimensions in two different columns
l'd like to create a chart/table for the following sample data. However the visuals would be based on two separate date fields such that it shows the number of tickets created and closed in certain dates.
How can this be done thru looker studio? The data source is just a direct connection to the sheet. I know how to do this in Power BI but I'm pretty new to the google data studio workspace and would appreciate the help.
Sample data
Desired output
